# Using eval() - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at pageLoad

Tags: javascript, dynamic-variables

first time using stackoverflow. :)

I am a beginner in JS trying to add values to a list of variables that may change based on the number of passengers variable. (ie. if numRiders = 4 I need to assign values to passenger1Name, passenger2Name, passenger3Name, passenger4Name)

I am trying to use eval inside a loop to do it:

```
for(i = 0; i<=numRiders; i++) {
    j = i+1
    var l ='var '
    var k = 'passenger'
    let nameJ = ride[i].passengerDetails.first + ' ' + ride[i].passengerDetails.last;
    console.log (nameJ)
    eval(l+k+j+ 'Name' + '= ' + nameJ + ';')
    console.log(passenger1Name)
```

I am getting this output right after the nameJ console.log

> VM321:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
> at pageLoad

Anyone know how can I solve this or approach this differently? Unfortunately, I can't change the variables names (e.g. passengerXName) to one that would make it easier to assign dynamic variables.

Thank you

Comment: Why such strict requirements about variable names? Why not just use an array?

Comment: Or an object? `const passengers = {}; passengers['passenger' + i] = nameJ`?

Comment: @ZacAnger Yes, however, even an object seems really weird in this case. It's a bunch of values in a structured order. That is clearly an array.

Comment: @CharlieFish yeah, you're right, if OP just need the passenger names in order, an array is what they need.

Comment: The passenger details are already in the `ride` array.

Comment: Also, please please please consider staying away from `eval`. There is almost no good reason to use `eval`, especially in this case.

Comment: Thx everyone for the comments. I will look for alternatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have since 1996 or so RARELY seen any reason for eval

This is recommended

```js
const rides = [
{ passengerDetails: {first:"Fred",last:"Flinstone"}},
{ passengerDetails: {first:"Wilma",last:"Flinstone"}}
]

const names = rides.map(ride => `${ride.passengerDetails.first} ${ride.passengerDetails.last}`)
console.log(names)
```

or even

```js
const rides = [
{ passengerDetails: {first:"Fred",last:"Flinstone"}},
{ passengerDetails: {first:"Wilma",last:"Flinstone"}}
]

const names = rides.reduce((acc,ride,i) => {
  acc[`passenger${i+1}name`] = `${ride.passengerDetails.first} ${ride.passengerDetails.last}`
  return acc;
  },{})
console.log(names)
```

If you MUST, try this assuming you have a window scope to add it to

```js
const rides = [
{ passengerDetails: {first:"Fred",last:"Flinstone"}},
{ passengerDetails: {first:"Wilma",last:"Flinstone"}}
]

rides.forEach((ride,i) => {
    let nameJ = `${ride.passengerDetails.first} ${ride.passengerDetails.last}`;
    window[`passenger${i+1}Name`]=nameJ;
})
console.log(passenger1Name)
```

Answer (score 2):

`nameJ` appears to be a string. So you need to put quotes around it.

```
eval(l+k+j+ 'Name' + '= "' + nameJ + '";')
```

But as others stated in the comments, defining variables dynamically like this is almost never what you really want.

Comment: Thx for the answers folks. nameJ is a variable I defined in the line above, not a string.

And yes, you are right that an array would make it easier. But I am trying to work around on those variable names

Comment: It's a variable that contains a string with the first and last names.

Comment: @ramon-gondim I'll reiterate again. This is not how you want to be doing things. I'd STRONGLY strongly strongly encourage you to think about alternatives. There are a lot of security flaws with `eval`. As I asked above, why do you need the variable names to be so strict? Avoiding an array is clearly creating way more problems than it should be at this point. I'd suggest trying to get back to basics and really focus on what you need and throw out unnecessary requirements (like variable naming).

Comment: @ramon-gondim Think about this: If you define the variable names dynamically like this, how are you going to access them? Are you also going to use `eval()` there?

Answer (score -1):

The option from @ZacAnger

```
var names = {};
for(i = 0; i<=numRiders; i++) {
    j = i+1
    
    let nameJ = ride[i].passengerDetails.first + ' ' + ride[i].passengerDetails.last;

    names['passenger'+ j+ 'Name'] = nameJ;
}
```